# Need walkthrough for choose file dialog or open file dialog to appear Awesomium

Tags: c#, wpf, awesomium

Guys i have the awesomium webcontrol that was available in the toolbox and it doesnot display choose file or any dialog box for uploading files(e.g. uploading pic/video in facebook).pls give the complete procedure on how to enable it.i am using visual c# and it is a wpf application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more info is needed.

- Are you referring to the WinForms or the WPF `WebControl`?
- Have you downloaded the latest RC? Download it [here](http://awesomium.com/download/).

The WinForms `WebControl` provides all dialogs. The WPF `WebControl` provides all dialogs too, however, folder selection dialogs are only supported on Windows Vista and newer. If the dialogs do not appear, you may have to handle the [`SelectLocalFiles`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_SelectLocalFiles) event. Make sure the event is fired. If it is but you still see no dialog, handle the event yourself and display your own **modal** dialog. Provide the result to [`FileDialogEventArgs.SelectedFile`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_FileDialogEventArgs_SelectedFile) or [`FileDialogEventArgs.SelectedFiles`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_FileDialogEventArgs_SelectedFiles) and don't forget to set [`FileDialogEventArgs.Handled`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=P_Awesomium_Core_FileDialogEventArgs_Handled) to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

What version of Awesomium? You need probably 1.7RC2 which has modal dialog boxes.

Comment: I AM USING AWESOMIUM 1.7RC2.the webcontrol doesnot show the dialog on facebook.